# Does it have memory leak?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, objgraph

I read [objgraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/#backreferences) document recently, and I confused about the following code

```
>>> class MyBigFatObject(object):
...     pass
...
>>> def computate_something(_cache={}):
...     _cache[42] = dict(foo=MyBigFatObject(),
...                       bar=MyBigFatObject())
...     # a very explicit and easy-to-find "leak" but oh well
...     x = MyBigFatObject() # this one doesn't leak
```

It show that "a very explict and easy-to-find 'leak'". Do this has memory leak? Is it the dict _cache?

Comment: its not a leak, its because there's always a reference to `_cache` as long as `computate_something` is in scope, so it will always remain in memory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_cache` is a keyword argument with a mutable default, which is indeed mutated in the function body. This'll store `MyBigFatObjects` instances permanently in that mutable keyword argument.

This is not so much a leak as a misunderstanding of the longevity of mutable keyword arguments. The function itself could still call `del _cache[42]` to delete these objects.

See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for more information on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

As dict is mutable, the changes made in it will affect also the caller, so the reference to two `MyBigFatObject` will be kept.

You should explicitly delete it (`del _cache[42]`), o rather make changes in own copy of dictionary or any other mutable object (you can use [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module for that).